# pipe/consume STDOUT as single string rather than sequence of whitespace separated words

Tags: bash, file-rename, batch-rename, quoting, command-substitution

I'd like to employ perl one-liner calculate resulting filenames using regexp substitutions. When doing dry run and simply printing the results it gives me the desired result (no quotes there yet):

`for i in *_\ *; do echo "${i}" $(perl -ne 'print s/(?<![_ ])_ /-/gr' <<< "${i}"); done`

but when changed to `mv` it breaks:

`for i in *_\ *; do mv "${i}" $(perl -ne 'print s/(?<![_ ])_ /-/gr' <<< "${i}"); done`

`mv: target ‘9781430249146.pdf’ is not a directory`

apparently perl's output is reinterpreted and white spaces cause problem.
When I put double quotes around it the perl code gets evaluated first by bash, which makes another problem:

`for i in *_\ *; do mv "${i}" "$(perl -ne 'print s/(?<![_ ])_ /-/gr' <<< "${i}")"; done`

`-bash: ![_: event not found`

Any way to quote just the output from command substitution (not the command itself)?

Comment: You could try disabling history expansion: `set +o histexpand`

Comment: I thought the single quotes (perl code here) would never be expanded… Nice workaround!

Comment: bash  also lets you use `set -H`/`set +H` to enable/disable history expansion.

Comment: I've converted my comment to an answer as it seems to have solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your command substitution to be treated as a single word by bash, you should enclose it in double quotes. In order to prevent `!` from being interpreted by the shell, you should disable history substitution using one of the following two methods:

```
set +o histexpand
```

or

```
set +H
```